# How to analyze unequal samples in linear and multiple regression

Tags: regression, sample-size, unbalanced-classes, mediation

I have three variables (sample size is mentioned below), and I want to analyze data using regression models as recommended by Judd and Kenny (1981) to see if $cc$ mediates the relationship between $spdm$ and $cty$ (I'm using abbreviations; see below for variable names). I have a unequal sample size problem, and I don't know how to handle it. I have read a few books and went through many articles, but none have mentioned or analyzed samples of unequal sizes.

**I want to run 3 models, of which 2 are with unequal samples:**

model 1: $spdm = \beta \cdot cty + e$

model 2: $cty = \beta_1 \cdot cc + \beta_2 \cdot spdm + e$

(where $e$ is error)

**My Questions:**

- How can I analyze my data in regression? Is it possible to analyze samples of unequal size?
- I read somewhere on the web that you can draw a random sample from the big sample to make it equal to other samples. Can I do that?

*Please provide the source of any book or article.*

**Sample sizes and variables:**

- a = 100 ($spdm =$ supervisor's participation in decision making)
- b = 100 ($cc =$ creative climate)
- c = 500 ($cty =$ creativity)

Comment: I see only two models and three variables. Do you mean that you have 100, 100 and 500 observations of the variables spdm, cc, and cty, respectively?

Comment: First thankyou for editing i'll look into rules.yes i have mentioned it in the brackets. and i did not mentioned third model as there is no issue of unequal smple size (third model is if spdm explains cc >> cc= b.spdm +e). there are 100 supervisors and each is supervisong 5 team members.

Comment: Are these quantitative variables? If so, the simple solution is to use the sum of *cty* to predict for the other observations.

Comment: varaibles are quantitative. sum of cty? can you explain. and if i have another model >> cc (n=100)=b1.spdm(n=100)+ b2.cty(n=500) then what can i do?

Answer (score 1):

I have made some assumptions that were not explicitly stated in your question. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Let me rephrase your situation. If I understood correctly, you have three variables $x_1, x_2, x_3$. Your observations are one instance of $x1$, paired with one instance of $x_2$, which is paired with $N_y$ instances of $x_3$ (number is not certain based on your comment). Each observation can be written as:

$$X = (x_1,x_2,x_3^1,x_3^2,...,x_3^{N_y}) $$

Where there are actually $N_y$ observations of the final variable for each observation of the other two.

From what I see, there is no sense in keeping the last observations as separate variables. They do not represent the same people, nor is there a specific order to the observations, nor are they necessarily the same size for each $x_1,x_2$, so it makes no sense to create a model from them separately.

One idea can be to take the average of these observations (suppose there are $N_y$ observations) to create a new variable, or:

$$X = (x_1,x_2,y) $$

Where $y=1/N_y\sum_{i=1}^{n_y} x_3^i$. If you construct a model, you will have 100 samples of each variable. Your three models now become:

$$ x_1 = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_2 + \epsilon$$
$$ y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2+ \epsilon$$
$$ x_2 = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 y + \epsilon$$

Comment: you are right. the idea of taking average sounds good. but i will have to do it manually, data structure i explained is from one organization, ill be collecting data from multiple organizations and observations for x3 will vary org to org. some org have 5 employees reporting to one managers and some may have more or less.....

Comment: Use average instaed of the sum. You will have to calculate an average manually, but most programming tools do this easily. Edited my answer to correspond with this comment.